# Approximation of the basel problem

Tags: approximation, pi

Why is it, that $$\sum_{n=1}^{x} \frac1{n^2} $$ is about equal to $(1+\frac1{2x})^{x-1}$? Is it possible to give an error term? My observation is, that for $x=1,2,3$ the two terms are equal but with $x=4$, there is a difference of $0.004$. Any hints or solutions are appreciatet.

Comment: As $\left(1+\frac1{2x}\right)^{x-1}\to\sqrt e\ne\frac{\pi^2}6$, I have to ask why you think they should be about equal to begin with?

Comment: But they ARE about equal to each other. I didnt said they will be equal to each other

Comment: $\sqrt{e}$ does approximate $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ quite good